# Rebase changes - without git

Tags: c#, .net, git, rebase

For a small .NET C# app I'm working on, I want to use the git merge/rebase algorithm, without git. My use case is game modding; a game has occasional updates pushed to my computer, they're rare but significant. I modify that game: I change a good number of those files, often in trivial ways. I would like to transport my changes to the new version of the game (which is downloaded to me locally) whenever it is updated. My tool is to automate that process as much as possible.

I'm aware that I could maintain the entire file history of this game in a git branch, perform rebases using that branch and publish a feature branch as the mod (first filtering out files I didn't change). It would be too much work, and it would get in the way of the git repository of the mod itself, which has different considerations for sharing, verification pipelines, and so on. Plus this rebase will often fail and a partial rebase is something I don't want to have to explain to users (I intend to distribute this tool). I don't want a git repository solution. I want a dumb solution with no side effects. The intelligence I need is in the rebase algorithm itself.

I am using .NET and I hope a function in a library exists that carries out this action. The game A (1.0) is being patched to A (1.1); my mod B, which is a collection of files from A (1.0) but modified, and some brand new files, should be rebased to (1.1) when I execute it. Where the rebase fails, because the 1.0-1.1 changes are too significant, I'm fine if it just warns me and lists those files but otherwise continues on. Then I and my users can look at those individually in our favourite text editors.

Comment: I'm still not quite certain if my question belongs here, in Super User or in Software Engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Diff Match Patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) which fulfils my needs.